# Twitter認証エラーになった際、こちらで制作したエラーページに遷移させたい

Tags: javascript, php, java, twitter

Twitter認証時、下記添付画像のようなメッセージが表示された際に、こちらで制作したエラーページに遷移させたいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この分野の知見が浅いため、見当違いのお話をしてしまうかもしれませんが、質問させていただきます。
[こちらのページ](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update.html)に記されているように、
TwitterのAPIの制限により、現状3時間につき300までの認証しかできなくなっているという認識です。
この上限を超えると、上記添付画像のようなエラーが表示され、twitter認証ができなくなるという認識です。

今回、ユーザーをサイトからTwitter認証に誘導するとてもしこの上限を超えた場合に、上記のエラーが表示されるだけでは不親切ですので、こちらで制作した案内ページに遷移させたく思います。

その具体的方法、
もしくは足がかりになる情報
・こんなエラーメッセージが表示されるよ
・裏側ではこんな動きをしているよ

等、教えていただければ幸いです。

このページを読むと良い等でも教えていただけると非常に助かります。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/150936

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/150930